# Reiterating over lists and dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.x

In the following code, why does my code not iterate properly?  I'm probably missing one line but I can't figure out why it doesn't work.

I have a function with the following test case:

```
>>> borda([['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['B', 'A', 'C', 'D'], ['B', 'C', 'D', 'A']])
('B', [5, 8, 4, 1])
```

Where lists in the parameter are rankings, each #1 rank gets 3 points, #2 gets 2 points, #3 gets 1 point, and no other ranks get anything.  There may not necessarily four choices.  The first element in the tuple should be the choice with the highest number of points, and the second element is the number of points each choice got, in alphabetical order.

I'm not done with the function, but I'm trying to get a dictionary of the choices as the keys in alphabetical order and the count of rankings as the values, but the output is a dictionary of only the very last element of the last list in the parameter.

```
L = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'] #This is referenced outside the function since it might change
D = {}
i = 0
num = 0
while num < len(L):
    num += 1
    for choice in L:
        while i < len(parameter):
            for item in parameter:
                if item[0] == choice:
                    D[choice] = D.get(choice, 0) + 3
                if item[1] == choice:
                    D[choice] = D.get(choice, 0) + 2
                if item[2] == choice:
                    D[choice] = D.get(choice, 0) + 1
                i += 1
return D
```

Comment: Can you provide sample output for the input you gave?  I don't really understand what you want your function to do.  Are you trying to get a dictionary or are you trying to get a tuple?

Comment: You have 4 nested loops. That doesn't feel right, does it? @jdotjot's solution looks good to me and it only uses a single loop.

Comment: @jimhark Thanks.  To be fair, I do have a list comprehension also.

Comment: Sorry, the sample output is `('B', [5, 8, 4, 1])`.  I'm trying to get a tuple, but I thought I'd start with making a dictionary.  I don't really know where else to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I'd do this is something like this:

```
import operator
from collections import defaultdict
listoflists = [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['B', 'A', 'C', 'D'], ['B', 'C', 'D', 'A']]

def borda(listoflists):
   outdict = defaultdict(int)
   for item in listoflists:
      outdict[item[0]] += 3
      outdict[item[1]] += 2
      outdict[item[2]] += 1

   highestitem = max(outdict.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
   outlist = [outdict[item[0]] for item in sorted(outdict.keys())]

   return (highestitem, outlist)
```

**Update:** 
I'm not sure why you wouldn't be able to `import` standard modules, but if for whatever reason you're forbidden from using the `import` statement, here's a version with only built-in functions:

```
listoflists = [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['B', 'A', 'C', 'D'], ['B', 'C', 'D', 'A']]

def borda(listoflists):
    outdict = {}
    for singlelist in listoflists:
        # Below, we're just turning singlelist around in order to
        # make use of index numbers from enumerate to add to the scores
        for index, item in enumerate(singlelist[2::-1]):
            if item not in outdict:
                outdict[item] = index + 1
            else:
                outdict[item] += index + 1

    highestitem = max(outdict.iteritems(), key=lambda i: i[1])[0]
    outlist = [outdict[item[0]] for item in sorted(outdict.keys())]

    return (highestitem, outlist)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  I should have mentioned though that I can't import anything, so I have to stick to fairly basic loops.  I know my solution is super messy, but I'm just trying to get a hang of this whole thing.

Comment: i got rid of the loop... check my answer :)

Comment: @user1797510 Not sure why you can't import anything, but I've updated my answer to give an example without using any standard modules.

Comment: @sureshw Actually, you did not get rid of the `for` loop, you actually added _another one_ in your list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

If you had 2.7:

```
import operator
from collections import Counter
listoflists = [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['B', 'A', 'C', 'D'], ['B', 'C', 'D', 'A']]

def borda(listoflists):
    outdict = sum([Counter({item[x]:3-x}) for item in listoflists for x in range(3]],
                  Counter())
    highestitem = max(outdict.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
    outlist = [outdict[item[0]] for item in sorted(outdict.iteritems(),
                                                   key=operator.itemgetter(0))]
return (highestitem, outlist)
```

Look ma.. no loops :-)

Check out http://ua.pycon.org/static/talks/kachayev/index.html to see why this is better.

Comment: Actually, you have three loops in here.  A `for` loop in a list comprehension is still a loop.